# Universal Image Loader using 2 displayer

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

How can I add a FadeInBitmapDisplayer AND a RoundedBitmapDisplayer to my Image?

This is my DisplayImageOptions

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.appwidget
.cacheInMemory().displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(1500))
.build();
```

And is it possible somehow to only use the FadeIn Effect once? And if it's loaded and I scroll down my list and scroll back up again it does not FadeIn a second time?

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I add a FadeInBitmapDisplayer AND a RoundedBitmapDisplayer to my Image?

No way in current version. You can create your own displayer (extend BitmapDisplayer) and copy code from FadeInBitmapDisplayer and RoundedBitmapDisplayer into your class.

> And is it possible somehow to only use the FadeIn Effect once?

Almost everything is possible :) But it will be not so convenient.

You can keep displayed images URLs in some map (`Map<String, Boolean>` = [Image URL<->isDisplayed]) and check this map before `imageLoader.displayImage(...)` call. If image for current URL is in Map (i.e. image was displayed) then use options with only RoundedBitmapDisplayer. If image for current URL isn't in Map then use options with FadeInBitmapDisplayer+RoundedBitmapDisplayer displayer.

Comment: Ok thanks alot! Will you implement a feature like this (For both FadeIn and Rounded) in a future version?

Comment: Maybe I'll make displayers like Decorators to allow wrap one another. Will see.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I add a FadeInBitmapDisplayer AND a RoundedBitmapDisplayer to
>   my Image?

Also had this problem. I used NOSTRA's great suggestion and here is my custom class:

```
public class FadeInRoundedBitmapDisplayer extends RoundedBitmapDisplayer {

    int durationMillis;
    String noRoundedCornersTag;

    public FadeInRoundedBitmapDisplayer(int durationMillis, int roundPixels,
            String noRoundedCornersTag) {
        super(roundPixels);
        this.durationMillis = durationMillis;
        this.noRoundedCornersTag = noRoundedCornersTag;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView,
            LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap((imageView.getTag() != null && imageView
                .getTag().equals(noRoundedCornersTag)) ? bitmap : super
                .display(bitmap, imageView, loadedFrom));

        animate(imageView, durationMillis);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static void animate(ImageView imageView, int durationMillis) {
        AlphaAnimation fadeImage = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeImage.setDuration(durationMillis);
        fadeImage.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        imageView.startAnimation(fadeImage);
    }

}
```

You can pass a `String noRoundedCornersTag` to the constructor. This enables you to give single `imageView`s in your XML layout that tag to skip the corner radius procedure (good for background images etc.), for example:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:tag="@string/no_rounded_corners_tag" />
```

A constructor call would look like this:

```
new FadeInRoundedBitmapDisplayer(Constants.IMAGE_FADING_TIME,
  getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_corner_radius),
  getResources().getString(R.string.no_rounded_corners_tag))
```

Comment: Already was able to get the job done. But could be very interesting for other ones who have the same problem. Awesome piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

I had to update @saschoar solution as it was not working with the current Universal Image Loader version (1.9.4). The solution is quite similar. Take a look:

```
public class FadeInRoundedBitmapDisplayer extends RoundedBitmapDisplayer {

    int durationMillis;

    public FadeInRoundedBitmapDisplayer(int durationMillis, int roundPixels) {

        super(roundPixels);
        this.durationMillis = durationMillis;
    }

    @Override
    public void display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageAware imageAware, LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {

        super.display(bitmap, imageAware, loadedFrom);

        animate(imageAware.getWrappedView(), durationMillis);
    }

    public static void animate(View imageView, int durationMillis) {

        AlphaAnimation fadeImage = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeImage.setDuration(durationMillis);
        fadeImage.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        imageView.startAnimation(fadeImage);
    }
}
```

You can use this solution to define the DisplayImageOptions in this way:

```
    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .displayer(new FadeInRoundedBitmapDisplayer(3000, 1000))
        .build();

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, displayImageOptions);
```